# Where is the Moon for the last five or six days?

Tags: the-moon, visualization

The date today is March 18th 2021 Thursday it's 6:00 p.m. I'm in the area of Sarasota-Bradenton Florida. I haven't seen the moon and it's been clear skies for roughly the last five or six nights... I see all the consolation of the Stars where they're supposed to be but I cannot find the Moon. It makes me nervous and I'd like to know why?

Comment: March 13 was a "New Moon", when the Moon was too close to the Sun to be visible.  Now the Moon is "Waxing Crescent", so you should be able to see it to the West, just after the Sun sets.  See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_phase.

Comment: Try using a free planetarium software like Stellarium, setting it to the current date and to your precise location (although even approximate would do), and search for “Moon.” It’ll show you where it is, so you’ll just have to direct your gaze in the right direction. Right now the Moon is visible towards the West after sunset.

Comment: See also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18563/why-havent-i-seen-the-moon?r=SearchResults&s=9|27.4581  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27186/why-has-there-been-no-moon-for-2-nights-straight?r=SearchResults&s=5|30.7775  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27104/moonless-nights?r=SearchResults&s=3|31.5634  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25666/a-moonless-night?r=SearchResults&s=2|33.1563

Answer (score 0):

Two things: You either have a new moon or waxing crescent moon that is difficult to see or even invisible to the eye. Or (this is more likely), you viewed the sky before moonrise.

Try viewing the night sky in a few days (it will be clearly visible), or view the sky later in the night.

Comment: I'm a night owl, so, I also smoke and when I smoke I go outside. so, I do view the sky all night long and I'm telling you I know where the moon's at and the stars are... that's my meditation thing I do when I go outside, I love the moon so when I couldn't see the moon and it's been so long, I'm like "well I can see all the stars so the clouds aren't in the way..." I just never had the moon disappear on me before. so I started kind of freaking out LOL